# How do I make a placholder always visible in a select?

Tags: html, angular, select

I have a select in an Angular application with some options. I would like to have a placeholder on it and, in addition, the whole select must be disabled under a certain condition.

This is my code up to now:

```
<select class="form-control" id="food" [(ngModel)]="myFood" disabled="{{foodStatus === 'private'}}">
    <option value="" disabled="true" [selected]="true">Placeholder</option>
    <option value="1">Meat</option>
    <option value="2">Vegetarian</option>
    <option value="3">Vegan</option>
    <option value="4">Main dish</option>
</select>
```

At the moment, the `disabled` tag won't work. It does if I add a `name` to the `select` itself. But if I do it, the placeholder won't be visible but only present among the options when I pick one: it looks like a functionality breaks the other.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to the disabled attribute:

```
<select [attr.disabled]="foodStatus === 'private' ? 'disabled' : null">
</select>
```

Note that you need to set null if the disabled attribute shouldn't be added. In html, the mere presence of a disabled attribute will make the select disabled.

Another issue is that you're mixing Angular metaphors - the [(ngModel)] determines which value is selected.

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltymmq) for a working example. Note how I've removed [selected] from the first option.

Comment: This works for disabling the select, but my placeholder (the first option, disabled itself too) is not shown until I open the select.

Comment: I've added a stackblitz with a working example. You shouldn't set the [selected] attribute if you're also using [(ngModel)] for data binding

Comment: This demonstrates the value of a stackblitz example :)